# numpy distutils erroring when trying to install with pip

Tags: python, numpy, distutils, mayavi

I updated my Linux distro to Ubuntu 13.04 today and installed all my Python packages.

However some of the packages encounter the following error:

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.X11NotFoundError: X11 libraries not found
```

I Googled but found nothing helpful. I would like to get this fixed.

Please don't link to "solutions" online. I have seen them and couldn't get them to work or didn't understand what they were saying to do.

I tried re-installing `numpy` too but that didn't do it.  I am not sure what else to try.

I would like a response explaining what I need to do on my end.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to install `numpy` from Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: @LevLevitsky I have tried that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You said not to link to other sources - but you didn't tell us what specifically you tried or what didn't work.  Without being to reproduce the error, [this suggestion](https://github.com/enthought/enable/issues/34#issuecomment-2029381) seems promising.

Comment: I tried pretty much everything I could find even that link.  It didn't work.

Comment: Ok, well you're giving us absolutely nothing to go on.  Here is the [source code](http://python-scipy-core.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.3.2-5ubuntu2/system__info_8py-source.html) for the system_info class. It lists the `default_x11_lib_dirs`, for example.  Where is your X11 installation located?  If you try to load X11 lib yourself in a script of your own, do you run into errors?

Answer (score 0):

Installing the development package for the X11 library solved the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```